# CoreLocation iOS Swift Region Boundary Radius Define

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am new to swift and iOS development and i am using CoreLocation Framework API
I define each region like this

```
CLCircularRegion(circularRegionWithCenter: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: queryLat, longitude: queryLong), radius: 10.0, identifier: tuple[location]))
```

I want to monitor 10 regions of about 300 meters around each other but when I run app and enter region it enter all region that i put in CoreLocation for some reason

I monitor all region with this function call

```
locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
```

and also when enter region this function call happen to tell me i enter new place by playing sound clip

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    //determine which region and play respective music
    NSLog("Entering region... " + region.identifier)
    //When you enter a region, play some music. This is hard coded for Testing.
    audioPlayer.playMusic(region.identifier)
```

but when enter longitude latitude of just one out of the 10 places but CoreLocation go to every ten place at once? I try to make radius smaller but didnt work

Could you friends help me? Thanks :)